# How to instantiate hypotheses with variables that are out of scope

Tags: scope, coq, theorem-proving

I'm trying to prove the following lemma about functions on natural numbers

```
  Lemma nat_funcs : 
    forall (f : nat -> nat -> nat) (P : (nat -> nat) -> Prop), 
      (forall n, P (fun m => (f n m))) -> P (fun m => f (m + 1) m).
```

When I proceed and introduce variables to the context, I end up with a hypothesis:

```
H : forall n, P (fun m => (f n m))
```

and my goal is:

```
 P (fun m => f (m + 1) m)
```

I would like to apply H and instantiate n with m + 1 but the problem is, m is out of scope, is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 3):

This just isn't true. A simple counterexample is `f x _ := x` (the family of constant functions) and `P f := exists u, forall x, f x = u` (which detects constant functions). The `f n` in the hypothesis of `nat_funcs` creates a constant function, which passes `P`. In the conclusion, `fun m => f (m + 1) m` is just `S`, which is not a constant function.

```
Example nat_funcs_contra
: exists (f : nat -> nat -> nat) (P : (nat -> nat) -> Prop),
  (forall n, P (f n)) /\ ~P (fun m => f (m + 1) m).
Proof.
  exists (fun x _ => x), (fun f => exists u, forall x, f x = u).
  split.
  - intros n.
    exists n.
    reflexivity.
  - intros [u no].
    specialize (no u).
    induction u as [ | u rec].
    + discriminate.
    + injection no.
      apply rec.
Defined.
```

"Needing" a variable to escape its scope is generally a bad sign that something has gone horribly wrong somewhere.

```
(* Explicit negative proof *)
Theorem nat_funcs_no
: ~forall (f : nat -> nat -> nat) (P : (nat -> nat) -> Prop), 
  (forall n, P (fun m => (f n m))) -> P (fun m => f (m + 1) m).
Proof.
  destruct nat_funcs_contra as (f & P & hyp & prf).
  intros no.
  apply prf, no, hyp.
Qed.
```

Perhaps you need to add more constraints on the variables involved/rethink the problem you were trying to solve with this lemma. Right now, the statement is far too general to be true.